# Jquery .slideToggle Issue in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

My site http://charleybiggs.com.s64567.gridserver.com/ is working properly in Chrome and Safari. When you click on certain boxes, specific divs load at the top of the page. In Firefox though these divs are automatically showing when the page loads. They are supposed to be hidden until a box is clicked. Anyone have any idea why it’s doing this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#music").click(function () {
            $("#musicinfo").slideToggle('slow');
            $("#fpinfo, #behindinfo, #behindinfo, #signupinfo").hide('slow');

        });


        $("#fproduct").click(function () {
            $("#fpinfo").slideToggle('slow');
            $("#musicinfo, #behindinfo, #behindinfo, #signupinfo").hide('slow');

        });

        $("#behind").click(function () {
            $("#behindinfo").slideToggle('slow');
            $("#fpinfo, #musicinfo, #signupinfo").hide('slow');

        });


        $("#signup").click(function () {
            $("#signupinfo").slideToggle('slow');
            $("#fpinfo, #musicinfo, #behindinfo").hide('slow');

        });

        $(".exit").click(function () {
            $("#behindinfo, #musicinfo, #fpinfo, #signupinfo").hide('slow');

        });

        $('#behind, #fproduct, #music, #signup').click(function () {
            var divLoc = $('#top').offset();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: divLoc.top
            }, "slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Miss important information: What the version of Jquery you using?

Comment: "They are supposed to be hidden until a box is clicked" How that?

Comment: Off topic: You could vastly simplify your jQuery by using classes instead of IDs.

Comment: Not a jQuery problem... you have a custom.php as css that firefox is not loading

Comment: Just figured out the issue. The divs were set to display:none and reveal once the jquery function is triggered. For some reason Firefox wasn't properly reading the display:none in my css. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Firefox isn't loading your PHP CSS file. There are no styles applied to `#musicinfo` on load.